# What's the meaning of "gavotte" in Carly Simon's song "You're so vain"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, lyrics

In the song "You're so vain" Carly Simons says:

> You walked into the party
>   Like you were walking on a yacht
>   Your hat strategically dipped below one eye
>   Your scarf, it was apricot
>   You had one eye on the mirror
>   **And watched yourself gavotte**
>   And all the girls dreamed that they'd be your partner

What does the phrase "And watched yourself gavotte" mean? 
Can anybody describe it to me please?

Comment: Did you look up the definition of gavotte? Was there something in particular that was confusing?

Comment: Of course I did. I'm from Brazil and speak Portuguese. The translation for gavotte in Portuguese is gavota and now I know it's a French dance, but I had never listen that word before and I'm sure most people in Brazil have no idea about what "gavota" means. In Portuguese, and I'm sure also in English, there's a lot of words that, depending on the context where they are used, have a completely different meaning so I was thinking maybe this could be the case here. Please forgive me for my poor English, I hope I could explain why I posted this question.

Comment: It would have been good for you to include the results of the search you did in your question--it would have both demonstrated that you'd done any research and also clarified the source of your confusion.

Comment: Many native English speakers have listened to this song and wondered, "What is she saying? What is a gavotte?" It is a fairly obscure word in English.

Comment: Thanks Sarah for clarifying that for me. Katy, I didn't include the results of the searches I did because all the results were pretty obvious, I mean, someone dancing some kind of music known as gavotte. But I was suspecting that maybe the phrase in question could have some kind of different meaning when used as a slang or something like that. Just to illustrate, the verb "to dance" in Portuguese may be used at least with three completely different meanings depending on the context. My English isn't good enough for me to explain it better than this so sorry if it sounds a bit confusing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "gavotte" is a French dance.

You walked into the party /
Like you were walking on a yacht /
Your hat strategically dipped below one eye /
Your scarf, it was apricot /
You had one eye on the mirror /
And watched yourself gavotte /

He was so vain, he watched himself in the mirror while he was dancing. The singer probably doesn't mean that he actually performed an 18th-century French dance. However, it rhymes nicely with "yacht" and "apricot."

Answer (score 2):

Gavotte has no specific cultural meaning so the meaning has to be inferred. Any dance conveys a style of movement. If waltz had been used you would imagine someone moving quickly round the room with hardly time to speak to other attendees. The gavotte is a slow showy dance and implies the person is walking in  a way that they expect to be noticed, they have brief time to acknowledge others in the room with short conversations and clearly intent on making an impression. And they would be looking in the mirror to see how wonderful they are. It implies a very vain, self centered person who is thinking how lucky are the people here to have me as a guest.
[An example of a gavotte](https://youtu.be/gON-DLL0jNQ)